# Saving multidimensional form components in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Not sure if the title is representative......

Issue: 
In a form builder I list fields available for a form, I want to be able to save the selected fields in different models.

```
FieldA -> ModelC
FieldB -> ModelA
FieldC -> ModelZ
FieldD -> ModelA
Etc......
```

Nested forms do not allow this. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Form object. More info : http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

In short: create model to contain all the fields you need. Do not persist that model in the database, but on save or persist create corresponding objects.

```
class FormObject
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  #put fields here  

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def persist!
     #create models here and save them:
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, giving this a go. Will update with my results when I am done.